# How to update the values of a column at specific row and column using pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

**Im trying to update the values at particular row and column**

**Here's what im trying to do:**

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[0, 2, 3], [0, 4, 1], [10, 20, 30]],
                  index=[4, 5, 6], columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])

df.at(4,'A')=10 #trying to update the value of row 4 and column A
```

Im getting the error like below, i couldn't able to figure out what might be the issue is

```
df.at(4,'A')=10
^
SyntaxError: can't assign to function call
```

**I have to use the .at() to fulfill my other requirements.**
Any help/suggestion is highly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You need to repeat your tutorials on PANDAS use.  Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.  Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: Good one @Prune ! i would be more happy if i get to know what im doing wrong.

Comment: Always helps to check the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.at.html#pandas.DataFrame.at).

Comment: As I said, check the tutorial for correct usage.  This is off topic for Stack OVerflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use squares brackets not circle ones:

```
df.at[4,'A'] = 10
```

Comment: no luck! df.loc(4,'A')=10 - SyntaxError: can't assign to function call

Comment: I updated my answer, again, not circle brackets!

Comment: That works, if possible could you pls tell me why .at isn't working. Im trying to learn..

Comment: .at is working, you used circle brackets, it works fine with square brackets, as seen in my answer. () is a function call. .at is not a function, rather an indexing technique.